# how to convert generic rdd to dataframe?

Tags: generics, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a method that takes an rdd and saves it as an avro file.  The problem is that if I use a specific type than I can do `.toDF()` but I cannot call `.toDF()` on a generic rdd!  Here is an example:

```
case class Person(name: String)

def f(x: RDD[Person]) = x.toDF()
def g[T](x: RDD[T]) = x.toDF()

f(p) //works
g(p) //fails!!
```

Does anyone know why I can't call `.toDF()` on a generic rdd and if there is any way around it?

Comment: It's too hard to call `.toDf` that you need to write function `g()`?

Comment: How did you get an RDD to begin with, though? Is there not an alternative to get a DataFrame (or DataSet in Spark2)

Comment: @cricket_007 `f` and `g` are not actual functions I am writing.  I want to write a function that wraps an RDD with additional functionality such as checkpointing so I can load the data if it's already generated, otherwise I will trigger the DAG to generate the dataset and save it to disk.  Dataframe has a few formats they can save to, but RDD just has `saveAsTextFile` and `saveAsObject` (whatever 'object' means).

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not using dataframe/dataset because there are performance issues that result from the fact I cannot change the number of partitions within the DAG like I can with RDDs (for spark 1.6 anyways, maybe they fixed that by now).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spark 2,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

def g[T: Encoder](x: RDD[T]) = x.toDF()
```

will work.

`toDF` is the added method by `implicit conversion`

```
implicit def rddToDatasetHolder[T : Encoder](rdd: RDD[T]): DatasetHolder[T] = {
  DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(rdd))
}
```

in `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits`

To accomplish, the signature should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
def g[T: Encoder](x: RDD[T]) = x.toDF()
```

is right
and you should use the method by this:
`

```
somefunc{rdd =>
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    g(rdd)
}
```

`