# Implicit class not working for Generic Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use **Implicit class** to simplify loading of data into hive table (using Spark)

Say for example: If this is my data,

```scala
case class Name(name: String, age: Int)
val lst = List(Name("name1", 24), Name("name2", 25))
```

I want to load data to table like this `lst.loadToTable(db = "somedb", table = "sometable")`

Here is what I have done so far to achieve the above ^ using `Implicit class`,

```scala
object TableHelper {

    implicit class TableUtil[X: ClassTag](lst: Seq[X]){

        def loadToTable(db: String, table: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit ={
            println("Table -> " + table)
            spark.catalog.tableExists(s"${db}.${table}") match {
                case true =>
                    println(s"Table exist. Not creating new one: $table")
                case false =>
                    println(s"Table DO NOT exist. Creating new one: $table")
                    // Create database
                    val ddl = s"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${db}"
                    println("ddl -> " + ddl)
                    spark.sql(ddl)
                    // Create DataFrame
                    import spark.implicits._
                    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lst).toDF() // Compiler ERROR
                    // TODO: Pending: Create table & Load data
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The issue is, I am getting this compiler error,

```scala
Error:(27, 66) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[X]
                    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lst).toDF()
```

The issue seems to be `toDF()` is not working when using generic type (where in my code `lst`is `Seq[X]`). Any idea what needs to be done to correct this issue?

Comment: You need the implicit Encoder[X], as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517200/how-to-convert-generic-rdd-to-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to fix the code (Not sure why my question got downvoted. Would make much more sense if the reason is specified). Thanks to @Worakarn Isaratham for the guidance. The code needed some additional changes vis-a-vis what is specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517200/how-to-convert-generic-rdd-to-dataframe)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object TableHelper {
    // FIX is X <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag    
    implicit class TableUtil[X <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag](lst: Seq[X]){

        def loadToTable(db: String, table: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit ={
            println("Table -> " + table)
            spark.catalog.tableExists(s"${db}.${table}") match {
                case true =>
                    println(s"Table exist. Not creating new one: $table")
                    // TODO: Pending: Load data    
                case false =>
                    println(s"Table DO NOT exist. Creating new one: $table")
                    // Create database
                    val ddl = s"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${db}"
                    println("ddl -> " + ddl)
                    spark.sql(ddl)
                    // Create DataFrame
                    import spark.implicits._
                    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lst).toDF()
                    df.show(100, false)
                // TODO: Pending: Create table & Load data
            }
        }

    }

}
```

`[X <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag]` did the trick. 
`ClassTag` is needed for `parallelize method`

```scala
  def parallelize[T: ClassTag](
      seq: Seq[T],
      numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism): RDD[T] = withScope {
```

`X <: Product` probably tells... the Generic type I am going to use implements `Product` trait (All `case class`es implements [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Product.html))

[TypeTag](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M5/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags.html) is needed for `toDF` method in order to give access to erased Types (in runtime)

...and now I am able to simplify the calling convention like this

```scala
val lst = List(Name("name1", 24), Name("name2", 25))
lst.loadToTable("somedb", "sometable")
```

and here is the result

```scala
+-----+---+
|name |age|
+-----+---+
|name1|24 |
|name2|25 |
+-----+---+
```